# How do I set onClick from React using document.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using document.createElement I am creating an `<input>`. How can I set the onClick property from React?

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.onClick = {setCount()}; //???
```

React cpde:

```
<input type="submit" onClick={() => {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.onClick = {};        
        document.getElementById("cards").prepend(input); }}/>
```

Comment: Where is the react code? Mixing react and document.createElement is probably not a good idae.

Comment: Added React code. Can I somehow add an element without document.createElement?

Comment: You seem to be trying to force some very *non*-React functionality into React for some reason.  This isn't going to work well for you.  What is the actual functionality you're trying to achieve and why aren't you using React to achieve it... in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in react you wouldn't use `document.createElement` because you have JSX as stated in the official docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

> We recommend using JSX to describe what your UI should look like. Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(). You will not typically invoke the following methods directly if you are using JSX.

If you still decide to use createElement, react recommends use of `React.createElement` if you are not using jsx. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

> Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(component, props, ...children). So, anything you can do with JSX can also be done with just plain JavaScript.

Using this your code would turn into

```
var input = React.createElement("input", {onClick: () => {setCount()}}, "");
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I unload this element in html? append() from JS doesn't work.

Comment: @Kirill I'm not sure appending from js is the react way of doing things, I'd recommend looking around stackoverflow for others takes.